# What is the syntax for specifying labels for a cloud storage bucket with terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, terraform-provider-gcp

I can create a Google Cloud Storage Bucket using the Terraform resource [google_storage_bucket](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_bucket#labels).

But I am unable to find an example with the `labels` argument, or find a syntax that works.

The following passes `terraform plan`:

```hcl
resource "google_storage_bucket" "report_staging" {
  name                        = "some-unique-name"
 
  labels = {
    key = "env" 
    value = "dev"
  }
}
```

but gives a 400 error on `terraform apply`

```
╷
│ Error: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid argument., invalid
│
│   with module.ndpe_project.google_storage_bucket.report_staging,
│   on ....main.tf line 130, in resource "google_storage_bucket" "report_staging":
│  130: resource "google_storage_bucket" "report_staging" {
```

I believe the above syntax would actually create two keys called 'key' and 'value'. This will also pass the plan stage.:

```hcl
  labels = {
    environment = local.env 
    created_by  = "me"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this syntax:

```
labels = {
  created_by = "me"
  deleted_by = "me"
}
```

Key/value pairs can be separated by either a comma or a line break.

The keys in a map must be strings; they can be left unquoted if they are a valid identifier, but must be quoted otherwise. You can use a non-literal string expression as a key by wrapping it in parentheses.

[Maps/Objects](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/types#maps-objects)

Comment: Thanks. And if I wanted to add two labels?

Comment: OK I discovered that the label's value can't have any spaces. That's why I was getting a 400 error.

Comment: Good catch! Furthermore it MUST be all lowercase 